# could not access to all LDAP Attributes in LdapUserDetailsMapper

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, ldap

I have a ldap authentication for my spring application. In order to add special attributes for my customUserDetails, I made a `CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper`.

I need to search the user role define in my LDAP. The Ldap is configured like : A specific user have a memberof list, which can have a `memberof` lists to, etc. So i need to browse all of this tree in order to find a specific group.

The problem is that i can't access to all the LDAP. I only have the attribute's DN of my user but i can't find attributes of the `memberof` list.

Here is my CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper :

```
@Component
public class CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

  @Override
  public CustomUserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
    CustomUserDetails user = new CustomUserDetails((LdapUserDetails) details);
    Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();

    try {
        Attribute memberOf = attributes.get("memberOf");
        if (memberOf != null) {
            List<?> userGroups = Collections.list(memberOf.getAll());
            userGroups.forEach(group -> {
                String memberOfDn = group.toString();
                try {
                    DirContextAdapter subContext = new DirContextAdapter(memberOfDn);
                    Attributes subAttributes = subContext.getAttributes();
                    Attribute subMemberOf = subAttributes.get("memberOf");
                    List<?> subGroupsMemberOf = Collections.list(subMemberOf.getAll());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

It doesn't work here, the subContext contains no attributes of the given DN name.

Do you know if i could browse subattributes tree of my `memberof` list in the Mapper ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn group dn exactly from ldap server administrators. Your user not contain a list that named **memberof**. You need to search like this;

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("uid", userName));
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("isMemberOf",
                CN=ADMIN,ou=users));
        List<?> userList = ldapTemplate.search(
                "ou=exampleUsers",
                filter.encode(),
                new CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper()
        );
```

If return anything from this search, you sure about your user is member of ADMIN